# Mockito stubbing - NullPointerException

Tags: groovy, mockito, junit4

I am new to Mockito. This looks a very simple test and this fails. I am writing this Groovy test and this does not work.

```
class Test {

class Inner{

    public String greet(){
        return "hello"
    }
}

@org.junit.Test
void test(){
    Inner inner = mock(Inner.class)
    when(inner.greet()).thenReturn("hi")

    println inner.greet() // throws java.lang.NullPointerException
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Mockito and Groovy does not play well together. There's a workaround though - https://github.com/cyrusinnovation/mockito-groovy-support

Comment: I'm planning to switch back to good old Java, Spring, Junit combination. Spock also breaks my existing Spring tests.

Comment: How so? Not sure I follow